# Pyparsing: Quick Reference parser definition correct?

Tags: python, pyparsing

Working my way through:

[Pyparsing Quick Reference, Chapter 3: Small Example](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/web/small-example.html) -

The example parser is supposed to match valid Python identifiers, so

```
'a_#'
```

should be invalid, like the author comments it to be, right? However, at the bottom of the page:

```
---Test for 'a_#'
  Matches: ['a', '_']
```

Here's the parser:

```
first = pp.Word(pp.alphas+"_", exact=1)
rest = pp.Word(pp.alphanums+"_")
identifier = first+pp.Optional(rest)
```

I'm not sure, so I'd like some feedback before contacting the author.

Also, I'm trying to correct it by constructing a parser that would only accept the defined character range within the whole string, so it wouldn't match a prefix of it. Can't get it right - any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes! Building up an identifier using two `Word`s is wasteful, inefficient, and just bad pyparsing practice.  I think the author was doing this as a buildup to showing how `Combine` could be used here, but afterword, he should show the better alternative using just a single `Word` expression.

`Word` has a two-argument format (clearly described [in the online docs](http://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.Word-class.html)) for just this situation:

```
valid_ident_leading_chars = alphas + '_'
valid_ident_body_chars = alphanums + '_'
identifier = Word(valid_ident_leading_chars, valid_ident_body_chars)
```

(BTW, this is equivalent to:

```
identifier = Regex('['+valid_ident_leading_chars+']['+valid_ident_body_chars+']*')
```

And if you look in the pyparsing code, you'll see that `Word` implements its matching by building that very regular expression.)

This will still parse the leading part of 'a_#', the same as a regular expression would. If you want your test to fail because the full string was not parsed, use:

```
identifier.parseString('a_#', parseAll=True)
```

For simplicity in writing tests, you can also use '==' - when comparing a pyparsing expression with a string, the expression will run `expr.parseString(comparison_string, parseAll=True)`, and return True/False depending on whether a ParseException was raised or not.

```
assert 'a_' == identifier    # <-- will pass
assert 'a_#' == identifier   # <-- will fail
```

Comment: Hi, Paul! I guess I might have started with your tutorials [Building Recursive Descent Parsers with Python](http://www.onlamp.com/lpt/a/6435) and [Using the pyparsing module](http://www.ptmcg.com/geo/python/howtousepyparsing.html), but I started with John Shipman's [pyparsing quick reference: A Python text processing tool](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/web/index.html) because it was updated most recenty (2013). Thanks a lot for all the work you've made available to the community on Pyparsing - and, of course, for the excellent exhaustive answer!